# Mark original email as complete when manually forwarded in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, email-filter, rules

On MS Outlook 2007 (12.0.6423.1000) SP2, and on Exchange Server 14.3.123.4002 in a corporate environment:

I have many different projects.  When an email comes in that doesn't trigger our automatic filing filters: I will click 'Forward Message', manually type in a project reference and filing address, and send the forwarded message to an administration team for processing.  I would like to automate the processing of the original incoming email once I've completed this task.

Can I set up a rule along the lines of: 
*If an **original message** is forwarded to processingteam@example.com, then flag **original message** as Complete and delete the **forwarded message**.*

I can work out the second part (deleting the forwarded message) but I can't work out how to *target a rule towards the original incoming message*, to change the flag-complete properties (after forwarding it).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some VBA:

```vb
Public Sub MarkComplete(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

    Item.FlagStatus = olFlagComplete
    Item.Save

End Sub
```

Now in your rule tell it to run a script and select `MarkComplete`.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for the VBA snippet.  How would I go about targeting the original message (Message A)?  I'm doing an action with the Forwarded Message (Message B) - but I need to apply the flag to the original Message A.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you'd need to write some VBA which triggers on the forward, looks for the `ConversationIndex` of that mail and then hunts in the Inbox for the last email with the same value. It's not hard but it's not trivial either.